# Normalize the posterior density for a Cauchy Distribution C ($\theta$,1) and a Uniform [0,100] prior

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior, uniform-distribution, cauchy-distribution

Using a Bayesian approach we have $$P(\theta|\text{data})= P(\text{data}|\theta) \frac{P(\theta)}{P(\text{data})}$$

Therefore, the posterior distribution will be proportional to
$$\frac{1}{N} (1+(y+\theta)^2))^{-1}
= 0.01 * (1+(y-\theta)^2))^{-1}$$

which is an un-normalized density.
What is the normalized density?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If you are asking for
$$\int_0^{100} \dfrac{1}{1+(\theta-y)^2}\,\text{d}\theta$$
the answer follows from [the Cauchy cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).